# How do I make two objects pull toward each other in a zero-gravity scene?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have two spheres in a zero-gravity scene. I'd like for them to gradually float toward each other until they collide. This makes sense, since in real life everything has its own gravity.

I have removed the gravity from the scene and created two rigid body objects, with a very high mass, but they just remain static and never float toward each other.

I can add a Force Field to one with a negative value which pulls the non-force fielded sphere toward it, but if I add a force field to both spheres, they again remain motionless.

How do I set up a scene so that both spheres react to each other's gravity?

Comment: Related: [Magnetic Spheres](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/magnetic-spheres) and [How to simulate magnetism In Blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/how-to-simulate-magnetism-in-blender/52240#52240). You don't have to worry about disabling the gravity, it is considered just as a global force field on the 3D space. It wouldn't bring in the Newton's law of universal gravitation behaviour anyway.

Comment: Also see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42109/electromagnetism-simulation/42180#42180 , this shows how to make bodies attract and repel each other.

Answer (score 2):

To make the your rigid bodies attract in your scene (assuming you already added your rigid bodies), you need to do this for each object:

**1- Add a Force Field**: In the 3d view, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Force Field > Force

**2- Make your object the parent of the Force Field:** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right click on the Force Field, followed by your object (The order is important) > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > Parent

**3- Make sure your origin is on the center of mass of your object:**
Select your object, then in the tools panel, select Set origin > Center of mass

**4- Align the Force Field to your object:** Click on your object > <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > cursor to selected, Click on the Force Field > <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > Selected to Cursor

**5- Modify the settings of the Force Field:** In the properties panel physics tab, you can find the settings for the force field. By deafult, the strength is set to a positive value, which will push objects apart. To make them attract, input a negative value. Note that massive/distant objects will require a lot more strength to be effective.

Repeat this process for every object in your scene, and you will have your magnetic attraction the next time you click play.