# How can i make to objects act like magnets so they push each other

Tags: force-fields

I wanna make to object push each other and have the same effects as magnets

Comment: This may help but it all depends what you want to achieve in your final scene. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42109/electromagnetism-simulation/42180#42180 This also includes a downloadable blender file for you to test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magnetic Spheres](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/magnetic-spheres)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/how-to-simulate-magnetism-in-blender